# UpdatePanel reset textbox background color

Tags: asp.net, textbox, updatepanel

I have an `UpdatePanel` within it a textbox with a background color of yellow and a trigger for text-changed for the textbox and everything works fine except that the background color reverts to white when I write some text in the text box and then focus somewhere else.

What is causing this? Thanks.

Using asp.net 4.0

Here is the asp.net markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <span>
            <asp:TextBox ID="sticky" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                 Text='<%# Bind("sticky") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" 
                 OnTextChanged="cSticky" />
        </span>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="sticky" EventName="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the css:

```
#StickyDiv textarea
{
height:170px;
width:185px;
resize:none;
margin-top:1px;
border:none;
font-family:Comic Sans MS;
font-size:1.2em;
padding:3px;
line-height:1.1em;
}
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#StickyDiv textarea:even").css("background-color","#ffff95");
    $("#StickyDiv textarea:odd").css("background-color", "#fe8ab9");
});
```

Comment: Please add the code, including the javascript and css that affect your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that when you do a update in the ajax panel your jquery is not called. If the text is changed you update the box to yellow and not call the javascript because it is rendered outside of your panel. To fix this you can register the script in you codebehide like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page,typeof(string),"JavaScriptCall",script.ToString(), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did in the folowing example

**in ASPX file**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="textChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**In Codebehind File**

```
protected void textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

Comment: but i am using jquery to add two different background because i have several text-boxes

Comment: You can use the same method for every text box. for every text box use onTextChanged="textChanged" ..In the code insted of using Textbox1.Backcolor use This.BackColor...i think this may solve your problem